# Get application/ld+json from external url using php

Tags: php, json

from this  application/ld+json i want to get example 1.genre, 2.director, 3.dateCreated, 4.duration, 5.uploadDate

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">{
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Movie",
      "url": "/title/tt2293640/",
      "name": "Minions",
      "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg2MTMyMzU0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTU3ODk4NTE@._V1_.jpg",
      "genre": [
        "Animation",
        "Action",
        "Adventure",
        "Comedy",
        "Family"
      ],
      "contentRating": "PG",
      "actor": [
        {
          "@type": "Person",
          "url": "/name/nm0000113/",
          "name": "Sandra Bullock"
        },
        {
          "@type": "Person",
          "url": "/name/nm0358316/",
          "name": "Jon Hamm"
        },
        {
          "@type": "Person",
          "url": "/name/nm0000474/",
          "name": "Michael Keaton"
        },
        {
          "@type": "Person",
          "url": "/name/nm1853544/",
          "name": "Pierre Coffin"
        }
      ],
      "director": [
        {
          "@type": "Person",
          "url": "/name/nm0049633/",
          "name": "Kyle Balda"
        },
        {
          "@type": "Person",
          "url": "/name/nm1853544/",
          "name": "Pierre Coffin"
        }
      ],
      "creator": [
        {
          "@type": "Person",
          "url": "/name/nm0528244/",
          "name": "Brian Lynch"
        },
        {
          "@type": "Organization",
          "url": "/company/co0221986/"
        },
        {
          "@type": "Organization",
          "url": "/company/co0005073/"
        }
      ],
      "description": "Minions is a movie starring Sandra Bullock, Jon Hamm, and Michael Keaton. Minions Stuart, Kevin, and Bob are recruited by Scarlet Overkill, a supervillain who, alongside her inventor husband Herb, hatches a plot to take over the...",
      "datePublished": "2015-06-17",
      "keywords": "minion,super villain,villain,invented language,teddy bear",
      "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingCount": 188589,
        "bestRating": "10.0",
        "worstRating": "1.0",
        "ratingValue": "6.4"
      },
      "review": {
        "@type": "Review",
        "itemReviewed": {
          "@type": "CreativeWork",
          "url": "/title/tt2293640/"
        },
        "author": {
          "@type": "Person",
          "name": "flint1961"
        },
        "dateCreated": "2015-06-27",
        "inLanguage": "English",
        "name": "Below par money spinner",
        "reviewBody": "I don\u0027t usually write reviews but this was such a disappointment that I felt I had to put something. Most of the good jokes were shown in the trailers, so if you\u0027ve seen the trailer then it\u0027s probably not worth the money. There were 3 of us watched this and although we all loved the despicable movies none of us enjoyed this. My son (11) said it felt like it was 2 hours long it was so boring. I can\u0027t really explain why it came across as so poor - but it just seemed really lazy and without Gru to play against the Minnions were just to simple. It was slapstick with no soul. The music although quite good didn\u0027t really seem to fit the film - just seemed to be tacked on at bit were they felt they should have a soundtrack and a famous song. Buy yourself a copy of despicable me and watch it again and again. Much better value for money! This just felt rushed, with loads of stock jokes, maybe hoping enough of them would hit the mark - they didn\u0027t.",
        "reviewRating": {
          "@type": "Rating",
          "worstRating": "1",
          "bestRating": "10",
          "ratingValue": "4"
        }
      },
      "duration": "PT1H31M",
      "trailer": {
        "@type": "VideoObject",
        "name": "Stuart \u0026 Dave",
        "embedUrl": "/video/imdb/vi996454425",
        "thumbnail": {
          "@type": "ImageObject",
          "contentUrl": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTgxMzc2OTQwOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODQ2OTgwNjE@._V1_.jpg"
        },
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTgxMzc2OTQwOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODQ2OTgwNjE@._V1_.jpg",
        "description": "Watch an exclusive video for Minions.",
        "uploadDate": "2015-06-26T17:14:58Z"
      }
    }</script>
```

to get meta tag im using this code

```
$c = file_get_contents("https://www.imdb.com/title/$id");
$d = new DomDocument();
$d->loadHTML($c);
$xp = new domxpath($d);
foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@property='og:title']") as $ti) {
    $imdbTitle = $ti->getAttribute("content");
}
foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@property='og:image']") as $im) {
    $imdbImg = $im->getAttribute("content");
}
foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@property='og:description']") as $ode) {
    $imdbDes = $ode->getAttribute("content");
}
```

from this php code I want to get and 1.genre, 2.director, 3.dateCreated, 4.duration, 5.uploadDate from JSON (application/ld+json) how i can do this? some help  thanks you.

Comment: Are you trying to get the values in JS/jQuery on the client side, or your PHP code on the server side? If it's the latter, the 'javascript' and 'jquery' tags seem irrelevant

Comment: im  trying to get example `"duration": "PT1H31M"`, from `application/ld+json` using that php code, so with that i get meta tag, but i want to get and some info from  `application/ld+json`

Comment: Thank you very mouch for your help, can you show example, to get the( duration) only that thank you very mouch

Comment: @Emma I tried like this now `foreach ($xp->query("//script[@type='application/ld+json']") as $du) { 
    $duration = $du->getAttribute("duration");` but is not woring!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but is not working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a JSON data into a HTML page.
So you have to 
1) retrieve the JSON data only
2) parse the JSON and process it

```
$id = 'tt0159365' ; // example id
$c = file_get_contents("https://www.imdb.com/title/$id");

// retrieve the JSON data
$d = new DomDocument();
@$d->loadHTML($c);

// parse the HTML to retrieve the "ld+json" only
$xp = new domxpath($d);
$jsonScripts = $xp->query( '//script[@type="application/ld+json"]' );
$json = trim( $jsonScripts->item(0)->nodeValue ); // get the first script only (it should be unique anyway)

// decode the JSON string we find into a associative array
$data = json_decode( $json, true );

// you can now use this array to query the data you want
$duration = $data['duration'];
echo "Duration: $duration" ;

$director = $data['director']['name'] ;
echo "Director : $director" ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, `duration` is working with this code, but `director, dateCreated and genere` is not workig! can you help me to fix this? thanks again.

Comment: if you can help me to get the `dateCreated` Thanks

Comment: `$data['review']['dateCreated']` 
You can use `print_r($data);` to have a global vision of the data tree

Comment: Thank you very mouch for your help.